# Data Tables and Nested tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am having real trouble understanding what is happening with Data Tables.  I create a DataTable as follows

```
var dTable = $('#sessionReport').dataTable({
        "bInfo" : false,
        "bFilter" : false,
        "aaData" : data,
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "fnFooterCallback" : function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay){
            var totalAttendees = 0;
            var totalTime = 0;
            var avgSatisfaction = 0;
            for(var i=0; i<aaData.length; i++){                 
                avgSatisfaction = avgSatisfaction + ((aaData[i][7]*1)+3*1)/aaData.length; // range is from -2 to + 2; have added 3 to each result to make range of positive numbers only
                totalAttendees = totalAttendees + aaData[i][5]*1;
                startTime = new Date(aaData[i][0]);
                endTime = new Date(aaData[i][1]);
                totalTime = totalTime + (endTime - startTime)/10000;
            }
            //alert(secondsToString(totalTime));
            //$('#tfAttendees').innerHTML = parseInt(totalAttendees);
            var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
            nCells[5].innerHTML = parseInt(totalAttendees);
            nCells[7].innerHTML = parseFloat(avgSatisfaction.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
    return dTable;
```

My data is formatted like this:

```
[ 0: "2012-10-24 09:43:03"
    1: "2012-10-24 09:49:47"
    2: "5002028"
    3: "Eamonn"
    4: "Dannys Memories"
    5: "7"
    6: ""
    7: "0" ],
    [O:....],
```

But I run into problems when I want to add a column with an icon to each row like in this solution 
http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows

I have tried using aoColumns and aoColumnsdef.  But not really sure how.  My problem is that table html is being built by the data.  So if there are only 7 items in the data array there will only be 7 columns in my Html Table.  How can I add an eighth column.  I want the beginning on each row to have a clickable icon.

And my html looks like this...

```
<table id="sessionReport" class="table table-striped fTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Start Session</td>
                        <td>End Session</td>
                        <td>Session Id</td>
                        <td>Facilitator</td>
                        <td>Group Name</td>
                        <td>No. Attendees</td>
                        <td>Assistant</td>
                        <td>Satisfaction</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="tfStartSession">
                        Total Hours
                        </th>
                        <th id="tfEndSession">
                        </th>
                        <th id="tfSessionId">
                        </th>
                        <th id="tfFacilitator">
                        </th>
                        <th id="tfGroupName">
                        TOTAL ATTENDEES :
                        </th>
                        <th id="tfAttendees">
                        </th>
                        <th id="tfAssistant">
                        AVG SATISFACTION :
                        </th>
                        <th id="tfSatisfaction">
                        </th>                           
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Any ideas.  I'm a bit stumped by DataTables documentation and they don't seem to provide any usage examples of either aoColumns or aoColumnsDef.

Many thanks

Comment: We can't help you unless we see the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: To learn how `aoColumns` and `aoColumnsDef` work, [go here](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) and look at the API for the sub-options. I suggest using only `aoColumns` until you have the hang of how they both work.

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger.  I had a look prior to posting here at the link you posted.  What's confusing me is that the documentation uses a key value pair structure for the data.  My data does not have any keys.  So I don't know how to identify them with the aoColumns